# ¿Tabla de usuario y contraseña , se relaciona con el resto de la base de datos?

Tags: base-de-datos

Tengo un proyecto Arduino el cual me enviara datos a la base de datos , esta tabla se llamara **"factorambiental"**, pero tengo que hacer un pequeño sitio web para mostrar los datos de **"factorambiental"**, cualquier persona no pueda ver mi contenido así que eh decidido crear una tabla **"usuarios"** solo para crear restricción , es aquí donde me surge la duda si sera contraproducente crear algún tipo de relación entre **"usuario"** y **"factorambiental"** , ya que del punto de vista mio no debieran ir unido ,puesto que un usuario no modificara nada de **"factorambiental"**, solo podrá ver los datos de **"factorambiental"** y al relacionarlas tendría ya una relación de ** y crear una tabla intermediara no seria apropiado ya que en ningún momento se almacenaran datos en ella.
PD:No soy un experto ,espero su orientación .

Comment: Amigo tal como dijiste no es necesario relacionarla, y la verdad No debes hacerlo, es necesario que lo dejes por separado, la tabla usuario según lo que explicas servirá para validar si tiene o no acceso, pero no tiene que ver con la información que tienes allí... Por lo que solo la usaras para dar acceso a esa información dejarlo por separado te permitirá luego tener mas libertad a la hora de modificaciones futuras...

Comment: @ASASCED  , no sé si habrás analizado la pregunta (que por cierto es valida) pero no se trata de un fragmento o un error de código, la repuesta va depender de su análisis, el único concejo que le daría a Alvaro (por cierto: bienvenido a SO Alvaro )  seria que nos de mas contexto de como lo quiere aplicar o cuales son sus requerimientos de este trabajo... danos mas información Alvaro (ve a [ask] para mas información, de paso podes hacer un [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio), la calidad de tu pregunta ayudará a darte una buena respuesta, mucha suerte a ambos...

Comment: @ASASCED no es un problema de código , Víctor HugoTirado muchas gracias , bueno los requerimientos son restringir acceso y mostrar datos recopilados desde un sensor en eso se centra los RF del proyecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para aclarar, según dices los usuarios son los que pueden ver la información, si la intención es eso entonces no es necesario relacionarlas.

También aclarar tu pregunta:

*Sera contraproducente crear algún tipo de relación entre "usuario" y "factorambiental"??*

Para tener una conclusión mas clara seria necesario explicarte que en ningun momento solicitas la información relacionada de las dos tablas. Tu análisis exige que **solo los usuarios sean los que puedan ver la información**, si las relacionas, implícitamente el usuario estará ligado a cada inserción de cada tupla de la tabla *factorambiental*. Esto se podría interpretar como que la información de la tabla *factorambiental* fuera agregada por un usuario (lo que estaría mal por el simple hecho de que vos mismo dices que la información será proveída de un Arduino).

En conclusión: *SI puede ser contraproducente ya que tendrías problemas de consistencia en tu información almacenada*. Lo conveniente seria aislar la informacion de tus tablas (en tu caso no deberían relacionarse)